# In C++, does adding a friend to a class change its memory layout?

Tags: c++, encapsulation, friend, private-members

Also, does it matter where in the class you declare the friend ? 
Does it matter if you add a friend class or a friend function ?

Comment: Note that technically, the C++ standard does not define a memory layout for non POD types.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No it doesn't. It's a purely compile-time thing: similar to access modifiers themselves.

Despite the fact that you write the declaration *inside the class*, you don't really *add a friend to a class*. You'd basically *declare something else as a friend of the class* and simply allow it to access the class's private members, as if they were public.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, it is purely a compile-time mechanism.